# draggeditem from list to group is null

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm dragging a listitem to a group. The list looks like this:

```
<s:List id="lstArtists" dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true"/>
```

The Group has dragenter- en dragdrophandlers:

```
<s:Group id="groupRemove" dragEnter="dragEnterHandler(event)" dragDrop="dragDropHandler(event)">
    <s:Image source="assets/images/trashcan.jpg" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:Group>
```

These are the handlers:

```
protected function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
    if(Object(event.dragInitiator).id == "lstArtists")
    {
        DragManager.acceptDragDrop(event.target as UIComponent);
    }
}

protected function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
    Alert.show(String(event.draggedItem));
}
```

But the draggedItem is null:

[image: Screenshot of the debugger]

How can I access the dragged item?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the item by : (event.dragInitiator as List).getSelectedItem or something like that.